# Get a Sum of integers from an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, iqueryable

We use a SQL database in our ASP.Net Core solution that stores things and can also store zero to multiple item types for each thing. We also store a quantity for each item type stored.  I need to be able to sum the quantity for an item type and return it to the View.

Here is what we use in the controller:

```
       IQueryable<Item> items = _context.Items
                    .Include(ep=>ep.ItemType)
                    .Include(ep=>ep.ItemActionType)
                    .Include(ep=>ep.Thing)
                    .AsQueryable();
```

The query we use in the Controller to get the sum is:

```
   int itemsum = (int)items.Where(ep => ep.ItemTypeId == 2 && ep.ItemActionTypeId == 8).Select(ep => ep.ItemQuantity).Sum();
```

The database has the following entries that should result in a sum of six being returned:

```
Id  ThingId ItemTypeId  ItemActionTypeId    ItemQuantity    
1   100         2               8                2 
2   100         2               8                1  
3   103         2               8                1
4   103         2               8                1      
5   105         2               8                1
```

This information returns a value of 3.

What am I doing wrong?

SOLUTION:

I'm not sure why, but adding in a date range from our Search model allowed us to do the sum operation on the IQueryable.  At least, that's what it seems to me.  Here is the code we added to make it work. We put this in after the IQueryable, but before the Sum operation.

```
items = items.Where(e => e.Thing.ThingDateTime >= searchThings.FromDateTime
                 && e.Thing.ThingDateTime <= searchThings.ToDateTime);
``
```

Comment: do you mean `&& ep.ItemActionType*Id* == 8`?

Comment: Also you can just do `.Sum(ep => ep.ItemQuantity)`

Comment: @Yitz, I did mean && ep.ItemActionTypeId == 8.  That's how we have it in the code.

Comment: @yitz, I have attempted the .Sum(ep => ep.ItemQuantity).  It returns a '3' for me.

Comment: I don't see why you need the eager loading `.Include()` to perform the count operation.

Comment: Do a `.ToList()` instead of `Sum`, and put a breakpoint after. Does it contain all 5 items in it?

Comment: @NPras, I tried the ToList.  I get an error that says I can't convert a list to a list.

Comment: @YongShun, we use the IQueryable for other things that use information from the Includes.

Comment: That error doesn't make sense with the code shown - are you sure you are posting the real code?

Comment: @NetMage I am posting the real code.  It doesn't make sense to me either.  I'm sure I have done something wrong somewhere.  I'm going to try the sample code provided in the answers to see if it works, and then build out from the sample.  hopefully, that will solve the problem.

Comment: `ep.ItemActionType == 8` - isn't this a type error that won't compile?

Comment: @NetMage I mentioned in one of the comments the code used is ItemActionTypeId.  I don't get errors when I build or run a debug session.

Comment: The point was how did that get into the post if you are posting real code? In any case "I can't convert a list to a list" doesn't make sense if you just replaced `Sum` with `ToList` (and changed the variable type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an issue with the translation to SQL and materialization of your query.  You may also have code that's applying an additional filter to the IQueryable somewhere, which will modify the results as the IQueryable result doesn't fetch data from the server, and additional filters (e.g. Where clause) applied prior to triggering results from the server via ToList(), Sum(), etc. will alter the query.

First, try running the sample code below and see if you get the desired result and then swap out the sample data context with your DbContext to determine if you

```
//Sample data
var _context = new List<(int id, int ItemTypeId, int ItemActionTypeId, int ItemQuantity)>()
    {(1, 2, 8, 2),
    (2, 2, 8, 1),
    (3, 2, 8, 1),
    (4, 2, 8, 1),
    (5, 2, 8, 1)}
    .AsQueryable();

var itemSum = _context
    .Where(ep => ep.ItemTypeId == 2 && ep.ItemActionTypeId == 8)
    .Select(ep => ep.ItemQuantity)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)  //good practice to avoid exceptions
    .Sum();

Console.WriteLine(itemSum);
//result = 6

//If your entity has navigation properties try excluding them w/select prior to .Sum()
var itemSum = _context
    .Select(ep => ep.ItemQuantity)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)  //good practice to avoid exceptions
    .Sum();
```

Comment: I believe I have identified where my problem is.  I just know how to fix it.  Our table of items exists as a Collection in our table of things.  When I query the list of items, the query goes to each thing only one time.  This causes two items and a total quantity of three to be missed.  how can I correct this?

Comment: Try excluding it from the initial query and the Join(_context.Things,...) as a secondary operation.  Shot in the dark but this my fix the Linq -> translation.  If you post a repro with two tuples like in my example.  I can definitely fix it for you.

Comment: I'm trying to configure an example for you. I was able to get this query to work in SQL.  Does that help in the translation?                                                                                ```select ep.ItemTypeId, SUM(ep.ItemQuantity) as total
from Items as ep join things as e on ep.ThingId = e.Id
where ep.ItemTypeId = 6 and ep.ItemActionTypeId = 8 and e.PersonId = 1 and e.ThingDateTime > '2022-08-01'
group by ep.ItemTypeId```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it as List

```
List<item> result = _context.Items
    .GroupBy(l => l.ItemType)
    .Select(cl => new item
            {
                ItemType = cl.ItemType,
                ItemActionType = cl.ItemActionType,
                Thing = cl.Thing,
                TotalQty = cl.Sum(c => c.ItemQuantity).ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I'm not sure why, but adding in a date range from our Search Model allowed us to do the sum operation on the IQueryable. At least, that's what it seems to me. Here is the code we added to make it work. We put this in after the IQueryable, but before the Sum operation.

```
items = items.Where(e => e.Thing.ThingDateTime >= searchThings.FromDateTime
                 && e.Thing.ThingDateTime <= searchThings.ToDateTime);
```

Comment: Sounds like it may be caused by eager loading of navigation properties.  If you have navigation properties, try selecting only the columns you need excluding navigations.  See updated answer for example.

Comment: @AdamCohen, I tried this today.  I went back and refactored all of my similar queries to include a Select and then a Count or a Sum operation depending on the data type.  I'm now unable to find an error and will do some reading on eager loading.

Comment: As a heads up, `.Include` statements effectively force eager loading of navigation properties, however you're EF entities may eager load (look into using `virtual` keyword on entity properties), and may eager load automatically based on the configuration in your DataContext.  Checkout - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager